# Склонение прилагательных и существительных с числительным «три»

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, согласование, управление, числительные

«7753 крымских организаций и индивидуальных предпринимателей получили субсидию».
Верно ли склонение в род. падеже после числительного?

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в счетных оборотах в именительном (и сходном с ним винительном) падеже количественные числительные не согласуются с именами существительными, а **управляют** ими.
При числительных два, **три**, четыре (а также в составных 23, 33... 93, 7753...) существительные ставятся **в родительном падеже единственного числа**:
*тридцать три портрета, девяносто три окна, сто девяносто три книги, **7753 организации, 7753 предпринимателя.***

Определение **согласуется** с существительным, зависящим от числительных *два, **три**, четыре*, в именительном или в родительном падеже в зависимости от грамматического **рода самого существительного.**
Перед существительными **мужского** и среднего рода прилагательное всегда стоит в родительном падеже множественного числа:
*три белых коня, **7753** (крымских) **индивидуальных предпринимателя.***

При существительных **женского рода** определение ставится в именительном падеже множественного числа:
*тридцать три новые машины, три черные лошади, **7753 крымские организации.***

[Сочетания количественных числительных с именами существительными](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html)
[Согласование определения с существительным, зависящим от числительных «два», «три», «четыре»](https://psyera.ru/soglasovanie-opredeleniya-s-sushchestvitelnym-zavisyashchim-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre_8718.htm)

Налицо "конфликт падежей". Предложение необходимо перестроить. Понятно, что и организации, и предприниматели — крымские, тогда от этого определения можно отказаться, заменив его существительным "Крым".

Возможно написать так:
**В Крыму 7753 организации и индивидуальных предпринимателя получили субсидию.**
Или так:
**Крымские организации и индивидуальные предприниматели получили 7753 субсидии.**

Answer (score 1):

1. Записать можно так: ***7753 учреждения из числа** крымских организаций и индивидуальных предпринимателей получили субсидию.*

Другие варианты для этого сочетания не подойдут, то есть делается замена, чтобы избежать конфликта при сочетаемости.

2. А конфликты здесь просматриваются **разнообразные**. Мы можем сказать: 7753 организации, но вот присоединить сюда еще и предпринимателей никак не получится. А если  так: 5 организаций и предпринимателей? Нет, тоже не подойдет.

Поэтому здесь не только конфликт падежей и чисел, но и **ограниченная сочетаемость** количественного числительного с **двумя существительными.**
К примеру, сочетание *50  организаций и индивидуальных предпринимателей* также звучит не лучшим образом, так как числительное можно отнести только к ближайшему существительному.

К тому же значение **собирательности**  неочевидно еще и потому, что второе существительное имеет **собственное обязательное определение.**

3. Поэтому использование существительного с **собирательным значением** легко решает все проблемы.

Примеры подобного оформления:

В конце года в библиотеке состояло 16.617 ***томов** книг и журналов*.
Мечтал, по словам Марьи, о большой семье, не менее *десяти **человек** мальчиков и девочек*.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Возможны другие редакции ответа, но во всех случаях   **числительное не образует сочетания** с именной частью.

(1) *В Крыму  7753 предприятия, в том числе организации и индивидуальные предприниматели,  получили субсидию.*

(2) *В Крыму субсидии получили 7753 предприятия, в том числе организации и индивидуальные предприниматели.*

Использовано другое слово в собирательном значении, при обособлении подчеркнуты  разные формы предприятий.

Comment: "7753 учреждения из числа крымских организаций и индивидуальных предпринимателей получили субсидию" - не думаю, что  корректно: 7753 учреждения из числа ... индивидуальных предпринимателей. ИП к учреждениям не относится. Варианты Риммы более подходят.

Comment: Разумеется, я не сомневалась, что вариант Риммы вам покажется лучше, да и многим другим тоже.  А значение  учреждения можно в словаре посмотреть: УЧРЕДИТЬ, что. 1. Основать, создать что-л. УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. к Учреждать.  У. общества книголюбов. 2. Организация, образуемая для осуществления определённого рода деятельности. ИП не образует юридического лица, но может привлекать к работе других людей.  К тому же дело не в самом УЧРЕЖДЕНИИ, а в необходимости СОБИРАТЕЛЬНОГО существительного (можете подобрать другое). Я стараюсь это доходчиво объяснить, но всё-таки, видно,  не получается.

Comment: А если уж заниматься КРИТИКОЙ (я обычно этого не делаю, но здесь уже вынуждают), то я скажу следующее. Первое предложение стилистически некорректно (ваши "индивидуальные предприниматели" просто "в воздухе повисли"). Второе предложение весьма далеко от авторского варианта. Но все равно вариант Риммы, конечно,  лучше. И вот интересно, если бы здесь было три ответа,  вы бы всем  оценки поставили – кому отлично, а кому неудовлетворительно. Комментарии для этого предназначены?

Answer (score 0):

**ОБРАЗЕЦ НЕКОРРЕКТНОСТИ**

Некорректным здесь было всё – такое удивительное стечение всего неправильного как в вопросах, так и в ответах. Темы можно просто перечислить по порядку, что я и делаю.

**1.   Неправильно заданный вопрос**

***Склонение прилагательных и существительных после цифры 3!***

**Содержание**  предложения понятно: называется точное число крымских предпринимательских структур, получивших субсидии, при этом указывается, что это разные организационно-правовые формы (организации и индивидуальные предприниматели).

Разумеется, вопрос звучит  не слишком грамотно, но дело не только в этом. Автор вопроса полагает, что  только **цифра "три" является источником проблем,** но здесь их больше.

Может ли количественное числительное сочетаться  с двумя существительными, связанными союзом И?  А что изменится, если они  имеют определения?  И надо обратить внимание на то, что первое определение – общее для двух существительных, а это неочевидно по записи.

Лучше вопрос сформулировать так: **О правильном сочетании  количественного  числительного «на три» и сложной именной части в числовом обороте.**

**2. Неправильная правка названия**

***Склонение прилагательных и существительных с числительным «три».***
По-моему, стало еще хуже.

**3.  Неправильный ответ первого участника**

Практически  в ответе рассматривается только **разные падежи** определений для  существительных **женского и мужского рода** в счетных оборотах  с числительными на  два, три, четыре.

При этом в стороне остается другая некорректность, которая является **основной.**  Давайте уберем все определения и что получим?  ***7753 организации и предпринимателя получили субсидию.*** Вам нравится такое сочетание?

При анализе заданного счетного оборота можно сделать единственный вывод: нужно изменить **грамматику** так,  чтобы **избежать этого сочетания**, тогда и  не будет никаких проблем.

**4. Неправильная оценка, а также некорректное поведение второго участника**

Цитирую:

*«7753 учреждения из числа крымских организаций и индивидуальных предпринимателей получили субсидию" - не думаю, что корректно: 7753 учреждения из числа ... индивидуальных предпринимателей. ИП к учреждениям не относится. **Варианты Риммы более подходят».***

Дается замечание по поводу  использования слова «учреждения» в собирательном значении. Оно вполне справедливо, но это слово надо просто **заменить** более подходящим – ведь **само-то решение не оспаривается**, а именно  оно устраняет несочетаемость.

Но   участник не  видит  всех указанных погрешностей  первого ответа,  не анализирует по существу  второй ответ – он делает очень поспешное суждение странного содержания: **если у вас слово не подходит, то у Риммы ответ лучше.**

Есть какая-нибудь логика?  А также  этика поведения и соблюдение правил на форуме?  В комментариях **не ставят оценки отвечающим**, там можно  только что-то уточнить, задать дополнительный вопрос.